# Status Script in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

As a newly SharePoint supporter, I find it difficult to get overview for my company's customers SharePoint Server; e.g. installation, setup, topology.

Is there a PowerShell script which can provide this information.

I was thinking about Server OS, IP numbers. SharePoint versions, status on build ( ex. CU), status of security ( FBA or Keberos) Name of administrators etc, all the information that is necessary for getting an overview of the farm.

Answer (score 4):

Without the use of third-party tools, there isn't one simple Cmdlet to gather all of this information.  You can, however, use a combination of Cmdlets to get the information.  Here are a few examples.  I do recommend going through the available SharePoint Cmdlets on TechNet to see what else suits your needs.

- SharePoint Version (which you can manually correlate to an SP/CU from info available on the web):

  (Get-SPFarm).BuildVersion
- SP Server Details (you can do some formatting to get specific properties you are looking for):

  Get-SPServer
- This post has an example on how to get the OS information from a list of servers (which you can get the names for from the previous Cmdlet): http://www.myitforum.com/articles/2/view.asp?id=10377
- Here is a full list of the SharePoint Cmdlets available: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678226.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Found a good solution on CodePlex

http://spsfarmreport.codeplex.com/